# Textarea newline prevention on Enter (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have:

```
$('#myTextArea').keyup(function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       e.preventDefault(); // Makes no difference
     $(this).parent().submit(); // Submit form it belongs to
   }
});
```

How do I prevent the newline that shows up right before form submission? `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation` don't work. I could manually reset the field text, but...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This happens because `keyup` is called after the text has been inserted in the text area.

To catch the key before being entered you need to listen for the `keydown` event.

So just change the `keyup` to `keydown` and you should be good to go.

```
$('#myTextArea').keydown(function(e) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't see that.